# Controller with Authorize attribute is called twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am testing a website developed in MVC4 and deployed on IIS with *Windows Authentication* and *Anonymous Authentication* enabled.

I had tested and confirmed from *Fiddler* that if controller is marked with **Authorize** attribute, then the controller is called twice in my case.

Code snippet -

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"BUILTIN\Administrators,SomeAdmins,OtherGroup")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    // Some code here
}
```

If I go simply without *Authorize* attribute, then controller is called once. I don't have clue why the weird behavior.

*Can you help me to understand the reason?*

Comment: “Controller is called twice” – what exactly does that mean? And how did you confirm that via Fiddler? Did you try *debugging* your code?

Comment: Try debugging your code from where 2nd call is coming

Comment: @poke I simply ran website in browser. Fiddler captured the requests. It show two requests to same page as http://SomeUrl/Admin.

Comment: If there are two requests, then that is done *by the browser*. This has nothing to do with the controller being called “twice” somewhere in the backend; of course if you are making multiple requests, you are hitting your server for each request. What is the HTTP response for the first request?

Comment: @poke The response for **first request** is *401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.*

Comment: @poke The response in **second request** is *Not Authorized. HTTP Error 401. The requested resource requires user authentication.*

Answer (score 2):

I think this is normal, as `Windows Authorization` is a challenge based protocol. First you will get a `401 (Unauthorized)` code and the browser will send the appropriate credentials. However, I think this is happening between your browser and `IIS Sever` before route is mapped and your controller action gets called.

More information can be found [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/odata-and-authentication-part-2-windows-authentication/).